# SQL Server CE WHERE statement behaving wrong? very confused

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce, where-clause

I am developing a windows mobile app. Right now I am just testing that it can correctly query the local SQL Server CE database. It works fine until I put a WHERE statement in.

Here is my code:

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection(
   ("Data Source=" + (System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), "ElectricReading.sdf") + ";Max Database Size=2047")));

   try
   {
       // Connect to the local database
       conn.Open();
       System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

       SqlCeParameter param = new SqlCeParameter();
       param.ParameterName = "@Barcode";
       param.Value = "%" + textBarcode.Text.Trim() + "%";

       // Insert a row
       cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Main2 WHERE Reading LIKE @Barcode";
       cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       DataTable data = new DataTable();

       using (SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           if (reader.Read())
           {
              data.Load(reader);
           }
       }

       if (data != null)
       {
           this.dataGrid1.DataSource = data;
       }
   }
   finally
   {
       conn.Close();
   }
```

The database contains this data:

[image: db]

Okay so you can see I changed the `WHERE` statement to use the Reading column just for testing purposes. When I enter "111" into the textbox and run --> it returns only the row `where reading ="1111"` and not the row that contains "111".

If I enter "1111" it does not return any data.

If I enter "1" it will return both the "1111" row and the "111" row which is the correct behavior.

However if I enter "11" it once again only returns the "1111" row.

Any other data entry of 2's or 9's attempting to return those rows does not work.

I'm not sure what is going on? This does not make any sense. It is not behaving like I would expect in any way shape or form. I know this must be a little confusing to read. I hope it makes enough sense to get some answers. Please help!

NOTE: I added the "%" before and after the text in an attempt to get better results. This is not desired.

EDIT <<<-----------------------I did have Reading = @Barcode, I just accidently typed Location for this question, that is not the problem.

Comment: You're comparing the `Location` column (which contains values like `Location1` through `Location5`) against values like `111` and `1111` - no wonder you're not getting any data back !! Also: what **data type** are your `Location` and `Reading` columns??

Comment: Your clause states `WHERE Location LIKE` and your examples refer to another column, `Reading`. Are you sure that your code queries the data you present at the screenshot?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916248/how-to-use-parameter-with-like-in-sql-server-compact-edition. Also, try setting the parameter dataType - param.DbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar or similar. It might not be detecting the parameter type properly and hence your problems. I know you mentioned you are testing, but changing the columns around wont help with this too.

Comment: Two recommendations: you should add a `using System.Data.SqlServerCe` statement to the top of your code and then just use the short version of `SqlCeCommand` (rather than the clunky version of always fully qualifying the type - makes things really really hard to read....) - and I would recommend putting your `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand` into `using(SqlCeConnection ......) { ..... }` blocks to ensure proper disposal (also allows you to drop the `finally` block just to close the connection - that'll be handled automagically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, some things to note:

1) As other commentators have noted, use the Reading column, not the Location column. I know you have mentioned you are testing, but swapping around column names and then changing code isn't the easiest way to troubleshoot these things. Try to only change one thing at a time.

2) If Reading is numeric, you are going to have to [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174450%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) the column value first.

So your query becomes:

```
"SELECT * FROM Main2 WHERE CONVERT(varchar, Reading) LIKE @Barcode";
```

Also see [How to use parameter with LIKE in Sql Server Compact Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916248/how-to-use-parameter-with-like-in-sql-server-compact-edition) for more help with working with parameters in SqlServerCE.

3) Set a parameter type on your SqlCEParameter. I've linked to the appropriate page in the code example below.

4) You are using ExecuteNonQuery for no reason. Just get rid of it in this context. It's for when you want to make a change to the database (like an insert, update, delete) or execute something (like a stored proc that can also insert, update, delete etc) that returns no rows. You've probably cut and paste this code from another place in your app :-)

5) Use [using](http://www.w3enterprises.com/articles/using.aspx) on disposable objects (see example below). This will make managing your connection lifecycle much simpler. It's also more readable (IMO) and will take care of issues when exceptions occur.

6) Use the `using` statement to import the BCL (Base Class Libraries) into your current namespace:

Add the following using statements to the top of your class (.cs). This will make using all of the .Net classes a lot simpler (and is much easier to read and less wear on your keyboard ;-)

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
```

A more complete example would look like the following

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   using(SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection( 
   ("Data Source=" + (Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), "ElectricReading.sdf") + ";Max Database Size=2047"))))
   {

       // Connect to the local database 
       conn.Open(); 
       using(SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
       {
       SqlCeParameter param = new SqlCeParameter(); 
       param.ParameterName = "@Barcode"; 
       param.DBType = DBType.String; //Intellisense is your friend here but See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceparameter.dbtype(v=VS.80).aspx for supported types
       param.Value = "%" + textBarcode.Text.Trim() + "%"; 

       // SELECT rows
       cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Main2 WHERE CONVERT(varchar, Reading) LIKE @Barcode";
       cmd.Parameters.Add(param); 

       //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  //You don't need this line

       DataTable data = new DataTable(); 

       using (SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
       { 
          data.Load(reader); //SqlCeDataReader does not support the HasRows property.
          if(data.Rows.Count > 0)
          {
              this.dataGrid1.DataSource = data;
          } 
       } 

       }
   }


}
```

Intellisense should be able to clean up any errors with the above but feel free to ask for more help.

Finally, you also might be able to set the data source of the grid directly to a datareader, try it!

```
       using (SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
       { 
          dataGrid1.DataSource = reader; 
       }
```

You can then get rid of the DataTable.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me make my code more efficient. Unfortunately this still has not solved my problem. I am still getting the same results. The data type of the columns in the db is ntext, do you think this has something to do with the problem?

Comment: @JasonNiggel, what happens if you hardcode your query, for example, try the following: cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Main2 WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, Reading) LIKE '%111%'"? Also note that you might actually be getting multiple rows back, you could be reading past the first one with your if(reader.Read()) line. Instead, try if(reader.HasRows) { //your code} or set the dataSource to the dataReader directly (if that works!)

Comment: Good idea with hard coding it. When I hard code the query it returns the same results as described in my original question. So this means it is not a problem with the parameter. So what is the actual problem!? This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Also try changing to reader.HasRows rather than reader.Read() just to make sure we aren't reading past the first record. Also, it's worth while trying to query the database directly; have you got SQL CE Query Analyser installed as per here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172926(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I am definitely reading past the first record, I knew this problem, I will fix it. I don't see how this would affect the results for the other rows though. I do have query analyzer, I will try that too.

Comment: Well I'll be damned. Getting rid of the Read() fixed the problem!!!! Thanks so much. Actually I was getting the error: SQL Server Compact does not support calls to HasRows property if the underlying cursor is not scrollable. So I just got rid fo that using statement. Do you know how to fix that error as I would like that using statement in there to avoid future issues.

Comment: When you call read for the first time, you are reading the first row. What happens then is that when you load it into the data table, it calls read again, which reads the second record - you've read past the first record, missing it out! So you have two choices; either just load the datareader into the datatable the way you were doing the first time and check to see if the data table has any rows (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0) or just try setting the data source to the dataReader directly. If that works and there are no rows then your data grid will be empty. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Main2 WHERE Location LIKE @Barcode";
```

to

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Main2 WHERE Reading LIKE @Barcode";
```

You are comparing the wrong columns.

Comment: +1 and it would also help to specify a **data type** for the `SqlParameter`! Not sure what it defaults to if nothing is specified.....

Comment: Hang on, is Reading numeric? If it is, then LIKE wont work unless the value is CONVERTed or CASTed to a string first anyway?